# Repository class and Firebase +with Room DB

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-room

I want to make firebase database communicate wit room Db trow repository class but i can't manage to do that.I try to save all the data from firebase into room Db and also to uptate all the fields on user request,i know also about firebase offline capabilities but i want to make my app work smooth and fast,and also do give a good UI experience with the android architecture components.
Will be good if i retrieve all the data in Main activity and update the Room DB by creating a new Object?
I have managed to create the Room Db but next step is to establish the connection with firebase.

```
public class UsersRepository {

    private Context context;
    private Database database;
    private UsersDao usersDao;
    private LiveData<List<Users>> usersList;

    public UsersRepository(Application application) {

        ///room Db
        database=Database.getDatabase(application);
        usersDao = database.usersDao();
        usersList= usersDao.getAllUsers();
        
    }

    public LiveData<List<Users>> getAllUsers(){
        return database.usersDao().getAllUsers();
    }

    public void insertUsers(Users users){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                database.usersDao().insertUser(users);

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }


    public void updateUsers( Users users){

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                database.usersDao().updateUser(users);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public void deleteUsers(final Users users){

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                database.usersDao().deleteUser(users);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }


}
```